# Elasticsearch pattern tokenizer to exclude commas and <br> tags

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-analyzers

`element` field is indexed with comma-separated values such as `dog,cat,mouse`. I am using this analyzer to split the above value in 3 elements `dog`, `cat` and `mouse`

**ES config**

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "separate_values" : {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "separate_values",
                "filter": ["lowercase", "trim"]
            }
        },
        "tokenizer" : {
            "separate_values" : {
                "type" : "pattern",
                "pattern": ","
            }
        },
    }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
"element": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "normalizer": "normalizer_1",
    "fields": {
        "separated": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "separate_values",
            "fielddata": true
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine but I could alse get values like `dog<br>cat` and I don't know how can I use the pattern tokenizer to split values based on comma **and** `<br>` tags

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use a custom tokenizer and provide all characters on which to split the split the text.

[char_group](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-chargroup-tokenizer.html)

> The char_group tokenizer breaks text into terms whenever it encounters
>   a character which is in a defined set. It is mostly useful for cases
>   where a simple custom tokenization is desired, and the overhead of use
>   of the pattern tokenizer is not acceptable.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "char_filter":  [ "html_strip" ], --> to remove html tags
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "char_group",
          "tokenize_on_chars": [    --> charcters on which to split text 
            "whitespace",
            ";",
            "-",
            ","
            ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: With this approach values like `dog<br>cat` are indexed as `dog\ncat`. Unfortunately I can't make them 2 separate values

Comment: @shAkur html_strip replaces html with their decoded values ex <br> will become  \n.  "whitespace" will automatcially split on it. If you are removing whitespace then add " \n" in tokenize_on_chars